# How to log HostInstanceId using TelemetryClient to Azure Application Insights from Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I need to log a unique identifier for the machine that my Azure function is running on. The traces automatically generated show `HostInstanceId` under Custom Properties in Application Insights, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

I am creating a TraceTelemetry in the function as follows and adding some custom properties to it.

```
TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
var telemetry = new TraceTelemetry();             
telemetry.Properties.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
telemetryClient.TrackTrace(telemetry);
```

Is there a way to add `HostInstanceId` to the properties of this Trace Telemetry?

I am instead currently using `WebsiteInstanceId` from

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

but I'm unsure if both are equivalent.